# What is the $A object in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, aura, basics

I'm starting to learn Lightning development. In the JS controller, out of curiosity, what exactly is the $A object?

I see it is used in the context of `$A.enqueueAction(...)`, `$A.getCallback()`, and `$A.utils`. Is it a collection of "Aura" utility methods?

Forgive the ignorant question - hard to search for documentation/explanation for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, $A is how you gain access to the underlying Aura framework, such as enqueuing actions, getting application events, managing the Aura rendering life cycle, and various utility methods. You can view the available methods using [AuraDocs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_doc_app.htm), located on your server at /auradocs/reference.app. You can access it using the [production](https://login.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app) or [sandbox](https://test.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app) links I've provided here. You'll find the full list in the JavaScript API section.

Answer (score 2):

The `Aura` object is the top-level object in the JavaScript framework code. `$A` is shorthand for Aura.

Refer [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_doc_app.htm)

Comment: The cheatsheet is outdated .$A.run and $A.log and $A.newCmpAsync() are not supported any more .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava What replaced `$A.log`? I see that `$A.run` should be replaced by `$A.getCallback` and `$A.newCmpAsync` should be replaced by `$A.createComponent` in the docs posted by @sfdcfox above.

Comment: @friendoflore I am not sure what replaced it but to log to console its recommended to use console.log() instead